# Can not erase bad character in custom IntelliJ plugin

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, intellij-plugin, lexer

I am creating custom language plugin for IntelliJ.

I implemented syntax highlighting and it works fine.

Tokens tree is built correctly too but when I type unexpected token something strange happens.

For example backspace key  doesn't erase character. What is more interesting for me is that I can erase this incorrect character using shift, arrow and backspace.

Second example of strange behaving is total code editor crashing.

Does anybody have any ideas how to fix it?

It is PSI viewer after typing some unexpected things

[image: PSI viewer]

Here I can't erase character at all
[image]

Comment: Please raise this issue at ["IntelliJ IDEA Open API and Plugin Development"](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979-IntelliJ-IDEA-Open-API-and-Plugin-Development) so that the IDEA core team could take a look at it.

Comment: Issue: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/5632746422290-Strange-editor-behavior?page=1#community_comment_5649368434066